# I want to set back few hundred tags to their default values. How can I do that in the shortest way (without setting all one by one)?

Tags: c#, class, struct, initialization, default-value

I have a C# application where I connect to a selected machine's control system and read several tags, and data. For these tags and data I have defined a few hundred variables in different formats (INT, STRING,REAL...). Before disconnecting from one machine, and connecting to another, I have to set the variables to their default values. Currently, I set them all one by one to their default values if the "disconnect" method is called. But as there are a lot of tags I lose the overview.

Is there a shorter way to do that? I got the suggestion that I should use structs, but the first point what I have learned is that it is not possible to define default values for structs.

Is using structs the correct solution for me? What is your suggestion?

My current code:

```
public class TagService
{
public int Tag1=0;
public int Tag2=0;
public float Tag3=1;
public string Tag4="";
// few hundred Tags   


public void Disconnect()
 {
   Delete_UserTags();
 }



public void Delete_UserTags()
{
 Tag1=0;
 Tag2=0;
 Tag3=0;
 Tag4="";
 //setting all the few hundred tags to their initial value one by one
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to reset _all_ the fields/properties in the class? If so, then `myTagService = new TagService();` (i.e., reinitializing the object) should do the job. If you only want to reset _some_ of them, I don't see any other way but to reset them one by one (unless you want to involve reflection and pass the names of the members).

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Tag3=1;` as 1 is the initial value of this tag?

Answer (score 1):

A property in C# does not have to have a backing field. For example:

```
int[] _intStorage;
public int Tag1 { get { return _intStorage[TAG1]; } }
```

This means that you can store the values for your tags in an array and index them using constants:

```
const int TAG1 = 0;
const int TAG2 = TAG1 + 1;
```

Now you know how to quickly clear your tags. Clear the array.

Comment: 1) Not any better than reinitializing the object. 2) Won't work if you have fields/properties of different types (which appears to be the case).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine The advantage over creating a new object is reduced heap usage and GC pressure. To accommodate different types, use a different array for each data type.